# What are $(\alpha ,v+W)\longmapsto \alpha (v+W)=\alpha v+W$ well defined?

Tags: group-theory

Let $V$ a vector space and $W$ a subspace of $V$. We have that $V/W$ is a group. We want to show that $(\alpha ,v+W)\longmapsto \alpha (v+W)=\alpha v+W$ give to $V/W$ a law of vector space on $V/W$. In my course it's written that we first have to prove that it's well defined. But what does it mean here ?

Let $K\lhd G$. If we have $g(x)=F(x+K)$, where $F:G/K\to G'$, to prove that $g$ is well defined we just have to prove that $\ker g\leq K$. What is equivalent to prove that $x+K=x'+K\implies F(x+K)=F(x'+K)$. But how can I do here ? I have that $v+W=v'+W$. How can I prove that $\alpha v+W=\alpha v'+W$ ? Just $$\alpha v+W=\alpha (v+W)=\alpha (v'+W)=\alpha v'+W\ \ ?$$
But My problem is that $v+W\longmapsto \alpha (v+W)=\alpha v+W$ is a morphism $V/W\to V/W$ and no from $V/W\to V$.

Comment: Hint: $v+W=v'+W$ iff $v-v'\in W$

Comment: Too many question marks. One question at a time?

Comment: @Jack: The question is how can I prove that $(\alpha ,v+W)\longmapsto \alpha (v+W)=\alpha v+W$ is well defined ? I want to use the universal property of group morphism, but it doesn't seems possible here.

Comment: Sometimes it's better to skip the fancy language (universal properties? Bah!) and just work through the definitions, as I've done for you. Once you do that once or twice, you can figure out how it all fits into that universal mumbo-jumbo, and then you can use big words like the rest of the cool kids...but you'll actually know what you're talking about. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question, "but what does it mean here?":

To prove it's well-defined mean that no matter what representative of $v+W$ you choose (i.e., maybe you choose $v' + W$, where $v - v' \in W$), you get the same result. Let's check that.

Suppose that $v + W = v' + W$, i.e., that $h = v' - v \in W$.

Then 
\begin{align}
\alpha (v + W) 
&= \alpha v + (\alpha h+ W) & \text{because $\alpha  h \in W$, hence $\alpha  h+W = W$} \\
&= (\alpha v + \alpha  h)+ W) & \text{associativity} \\
&= (\alpha v + \alpha  (v'- v))+ W) & \text{defn of $h$} \\
&= (\alpha v + \alpha  v'- \alpha v)+ W) & \text{distributivity} \\
&= ( \alpha  v')+ W) & \text{cancellation},
\end{align}
as required.

Comment: so there is nothing with the universal property of morphism group ? Because always when my teacher ask that an application is well define, we have to prove that $v+W=v'+W$ then $F(v+W)=F(v'+W)$

Comment: This is abuse of notation. You cannot write $F(v+W)$ if you don't know it is well defined.

Comment: I think that OP means is that "whenever $v + W  = v' + W$, we have to show that the result of applying the definition using $v$ is the same as the result of applying the description using $v'$", and the letter "F" here should be taken as describing the symbol-dependent definition rather than some function on the quotient space. But I agree that it's an abuse...